# Woocommerce Booking Set Price Not Working

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-bookings

Hello I have been trying to create a woocommerce booking by code, I have managed to create a booking and add it to the user's cart. The problem is that I cannot set the booking's price. I have tried multiple solutions such as these:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_add_cart_item', 'tsc_booking_woocommerce_add_cart_item', 99, 1);
function tsc_booking_woocommerce_add_cart_item($cart_item)
{
    try {
        session_start();
        if (!empty($cart_item['booking']) && isset($cart_item['booking'] 
        ['_cost']) && '' !== $cart_item['booking']['_cost']) {
            $cart_item['data']->set_price(100);
            $cart_item['custom_price'] = 100;
        }
        return $cart_item;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        throw $e;
    }
}


add_filter('woocommerce_get_cart_item_from_session', 'tsc_booking_woocommerce_get_cart_item_from_session', 99, 3);
function  tsc_booking_woocommerce_get_cart_item_from_session($woo_data, $values, $key)
{
    if (!isset($woo_data['custom_price']) || empty($woo_data['custom_price'])) {
        return $woo_data;
    }
    $woo_data['data']->set_price($woo_data['custom_price']);
    return $woo_data;
}

add_filter('woocommerce_bookings_calculated_booking_cost', 'tsc_booking_woocommerce_bookings_calculated_booking_cost', 99, 3);
function tsc_booking_woocommerce_bookings_calculated_booking_cost($booking_cost, $booking, $posted)
    {
        try {
            return 100;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            throw $e;
        }
    }
```

But they don't seem to work.

The documented solution would be to use the "woocommerce_before_calculate_totals" hook but it is not working.
I have debugged the code and all the function are being invoked and no there does not seem to be any errors.

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'tsc_booking_woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 1000, 1);
function tsc_booking_woocommerce_before_calculate_totals($cart)
{
    if (is_admin() && !defined('DOING_AJAX'))
        return;
    
    if (did_action('woocommerce_before_calculate_totals') >= 2)
        return;
    
    foreach ($cart->get_cart() as $cart_item) {
        $cart_item['data']->set_price(100);
    }
}
```

I am pretty sure this worked for a normal WC_Product is there something else to do for a Booking product?

Thanks,

Comment: Where do you/is the hook and callback to the function?

Comment: add_action('woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'tsc_booking_woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 1000, 1);

Comment: Please add additional information to your question, opposite as a comment. 
have you debugged your function? is it actually called?

Answer (score 0):

I got it...

Just in case anyone gets an headache like the one I just got.

The reason the price was reset to 0 in the cart was because of another plugin "Woocommerce Membership". The product had a discount price of 100€ for members and because I was using a testing price of 100€... the two would add up to 0. I guess the membership plugin has a lower priority when setting the product price.